# How to increase text size in Dreamweaver 8?

Tags: dreamweaver, text-editor

Can someone please help me increasing the text size globally in Dreamweaver. Like in Notepad++ we can scroll in/out while pressing CTRL. Even the menu is hidden in Dreamweaver that shows zooming options.

[image]

[image]

Comment: in dreamweaver preferences you can define font as well as font size.

Comment: could you plz explain me for dreamweaver 8

Answer (score 6):

> Click on `EDIT` -> `PREFERENCES` -> `Fonts` (Select from Category) -> Change
>   Font sizes as required -> `OK` (Click Ok)

Comment: any shot key available for it?

Comment: Press: Ctrl + U

Answer (score 1):

Go to the last button on the left hand side  of code window . Go on that button name of button is "format source code" then select "code format setting" then select "font" in that  last option "code view" select any font e.g. "arial" size "14pt" or any then you can see the change in code window font.

Comment: Can you insert some printscreens (and punctuations, for example bullets for a list) in your answer? That will increase the quality of your answer!

Answer (score 0):

see the screen  1st screen . go to the last button of left side code window

Answer (score 0):

FYI, for CS7....
Edit >> Preferences >> Fonts >> Make changes as nec. to the "Code view" Font and Size options.

Answer (score -1):

In the code window you can see line numbers 1 to 15.

On the left hand side you can see one strip of buttons

First button is "open document" in that row select the last button "format source code"

Then select "code format setting"

In category select "font"

In code view: select font name and size